# Storing counter in shelve file without initializing - Python

Tags: python, shelve

The program generates a variable guest**n** with **n** incrementing for each guest. I want the program to start at the last guest number whenever it runs.

I can only get the program to work by initializing `shelf_file["count"]`, if I don't I get a key error.

```
shelf_file = shelve.open("mydata")

shelf_file["count"] = 0   #I want to get rid of this line

shelf_file["count"] += 1
guest_id = "guest" + str(shelf_file["count"])
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `shelf_file['count'] = shelf_file.get('count', 0)`?  Or you may want to consider using a defaultdict.

Comment: I get a TypeError with that code, seems to initialize with None. I never thought about using dictionary methods so I'll expierement more with those. And I'll have a look into defaultdict, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with `shelf_file.setdefault("count", 1)`

Thanks @Jkdc for pointing me in the right direction.

For some reason `shelf_file` kept storing "None" until I deleted the files in the directory.